# link_to_if throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

Im trying to fathom out link_to_if,

While calling:

```
<%= link_to_if(!current_user.nil?, "My profile", profile_path(current_user.profile)) %> <br>
<%= link_to_if(!current_user.nil?, "Edit profile", edit_profile_path(current_user.id) {}) %> <br>
```

Its throwing this error.

> undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass

of course because i have logged out but shouldn't the link_to_if stop `profile_path(current_user.profile)` from being called or i have i implemented it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but shouldn't the `link_to_if` stop

`link_to_if` hasn't even "started" yet. Before calling a method, all its arguments are evaluated. In this case, both condition AND the `profile_path` (which fails). You should wrap the link in an external conditional.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "My profile", profile_path(current_user.profile) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following

If you need without external condition then looks like this

```
<%= link_to_unless(current_user.nil?, "My profile", profile_path(current_user.profile)) %>
```

Or

```
<% if current_user %>
   <%= link_to "My profile", profile_path(current_user.profile) %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My example from existing project like `<%= link_to_unless params[:view].blank?, image_tag("views/full.png", :size => "15x10"), query_parameters.merge(:view => nil, :page => nil), :title => "Full View" %>`,  anyway, I have updated based [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless)

Comment: Read my answer, you'll know why.

Comment: Ok, Thanks very much @SergioTulentsev